# Book I read in the 70's or 80's; I think the title was "The * mask"

Tags: story-identification, books, virtual-worlds

The book was a fantasy book about a group of people working together and at the end you discover that they are all crew mates on a spaceship and the life they were living out was really a virtual reality the ship put them in while they were traveling (cryosleep) or something like that.  Does anyone remember that book?

Comment: Could it be "A Maze of Death" by Philip K. Dick?

Comment: Thanks.  That might be it.  Seems very similar if it is not the one.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

"A Maze of Death" by Philip K. Dick

Synopsis from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Maze_of_Death):

> The plot revolves around fourteen colonists of the planet Delmak-O.
>   They are: Betty Jo Berm, a linguist; elderly Bert Kostler, settlement
>   custodian; Maggie Walsh, a theologian; Ignatz Thugg, who oversees
>   thermoplastics; Milton Babble, a physician; Wade Frazer, a
>   psychologist; Tony Dunkelwelt, a geologist; Glen Belsnor, who
>   specialises in telecommunications; Susie Smart, a typist; Roberta
>   Rockingham, a sociologist; Ben Tallchief, a naturalist; Seth and Mary
>   Morley, a marine biologist couple; and Ned Russell, an economist.

[...]

> One by one, the characters Tallchief, Smart, Berm, Dunkelwelt, Kostler
>   and Walsh either kill themselves or are killed under mysterious
>   circumstances.

[...]

> All of them, including the colonists thought to be dead, awake to find
>   that they are actually the crew of the spaceship Persus 9, stranded in
>   orbit around a dead star with no way of calling for help. Their
>   experiences had been a kind of virtual reality, a computer-generated
>   religion that synthesized their beliefs. Their dormancy should save
>   energy of the ship's life support systems for the unlikely case
>   someone would detect the stranded ship and rescue them. It becomes
>   clear that they already completed several cycles of virtual reality
>   dormancy, due to the gradual disintegration each more nightmarish than
>   the previous one.